# Is it possible for the sum of an odd number of even numbers to equal the sum of an even number of even numbers if all numbers are distinct?

Tags: number-theory

> Is it possible for the sum of an odd number of even numbers to equal the sum of an even number of even numbers if all numbers are distinct?

I was doing a math question, and I need to prove this as a lemma if it is true. I am not sure how to prove this statement or if it is actually true.

Comment: $6=2+4{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: $2+6+8=4+12{}$?

Answer (score 1):

$2+4+12=8+10$. So the answer is yes.